# Как преобразовать результат работы алгоритма Дейкстры в строки?

Tags: python, алгоритм, list

У меня словарь, по которому легко можно понять какой оптимальный путь из пункта 1 в пункт n через другие пункты.

Допустим, n = 6
Тогда по словарю видим, что из пункта 6 нужно идти в пункт 3, из пункта 3 в пункт 1. В этом случае нужно вывести "136". Так на дорогах мы заплатим меньше всего (у каждой дороги своя цена, это уже всё посчитано)

Как мне сделать похожий алгоритм, если оптимальных пунктов несколько (например как в пунктах 4,5,7)?

Это должно работать примерно так:

```
dictNodes = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: [1, 3], 5: [4, 6], 6: 3, 7: [1, 2, 5]}
target = 7
#---Тут код---

#-------------
#Пример вывода:
#17
#127
#1457
#13457
#13657
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте рекурсию, вызывая следующий уровень для всех значений ключа в цикле

Или примените очередь, в которую складываются все значения, затем извлекается первое, и делается спуск до первого узла. Повторять, пока очередь не опустеет.